# Is there any way to determine the handedness of a molecule through remote spectroscopy?

Tags: symmetry, spectroscopy, chirality

In following publications of astronomy, one will come across findings of various molecules (sometimes organic) that have been detected spectroscopically.

Is there any way to determine the handedness of such molecules? I ask because it would be interesting to know if the asymmetry that exists in biological molecules on earth persists throughout the cosmos.

I understand that there is reason to believe it does due to the left handedness of the weak force. The issue seems similar to trying to differentiate the spectra of an atom and its anti-particle counterpart (no difference I believe).

Yet, if there is some asymmetry such as the organic molecules in a strong magnetic field (which we might be able to determine remotely) then maybe we could tell the difference?

Comment: Left- and right-circurlarly polarised electromagnetic waves propagates differently in chiral media. This is used in lab measurement. Not sure how applicable it would be to your case though.

Comment: http://www.pnas.org/content/106/19/7816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a commenter pointed out, one "easy" way of detecting the handedness of a molecule is to measure the propagation of left- and right-circularly polarized light through a cloud or solution containing it. This is a standard procedure in organic synthesis on Earth.

Regarding antiparticle counterparts, antimatter in general is extremely rare, rare enough that you wouldn't realistically find a molecule of antimatter complex enough to exhibit chirality.

Interestingly enough, we only just last year started detecting chiral molecules in space (https://public.nrao.edu/news/2016-chiral-gbt/), and the current plan is to do exactly as the commenter suggested - look for sources of polarized light that shine into the cloud containing the molecule, and examine their propagation through the cloud.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!